# How to edit .dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I made the file .dll using the C++ language and compile with microsoft visual studio 2012, and c++ file his deleted.

I've tried using reflector, CFFExplorer, LINQPad4 and it's all useless files etc. I cannot open the back. I want to add new features on my .dll files.

Is it possible my .dll file on reopen?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: You're looking for a "C++ decompiler".  Results will... vary.  Consider this a lesson learned to always back up important data.

Comment: oh i forget i ever use Boomerang C++ Decompiler, OllyDbg and useless

Comment: There's a difference between "useless" and "doesn't do specifically what I need."  The simple fact is that you have lost something.  It's unlikely that you can derive what you have lost.  You'll probably need to re-implement the code.